# How does the fork() know whether it is in child process and in parent process?

Tags: linux, process, operating-system, fork, exec

When a fork() system call gets executed , the processor turns into kernel mode.

Thus at the end of the fork call a new process has spawned with a copy of almost all the constructs of the calling process (like the stack , user data and user programs etc.)

It is also clear from many very well answered explanations that how a process (a programmer) can identify the difference between a child process and a parent process. As per the many documented answers on SO and elsewhere:

> if a call to **fork()** returns 0 it means that it is the child process that called the **fork()**. While if the return value of `fork()` is a positive integer, it means that the **fork()** was executed in the parent process and the returned positive integer is a PID of the child process. Ignoring the case of negative value returns for the sake of brevity.

*Hopefully my understanding above is correct :fingers_crossed:*

However, the below is what I am trying to understand better and hopefully in more details/depth:

*(please pardon my ignorance on the subject.I am just curious to understand this better from an internal perspective. This topic and my want to get a clearer understanding around it has literally started hijacking my dreams now :P )*

How does the system call (that gets invoked when **fork()** is called) know that now it is being executed as part of the child process **and hence** should return 0?

Alternatively put, how does the system call know that it is being executed in the context of the parent process **and hence** it should now return the child process' PID this time and not 0?

Or is it such that out of the 2 processes, since both are exact replicas, one of them randomly gets the return value as 0 and the other as the PID **and then** based on the which one got what return value, it is considered parent and child accordingly? :thinking_face:

I'd be happy to be guided in the direction with any resources that I should go through. I would really appreciate any help in this direction actually. :pray:

Comment: Please take several hours to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which explains very well this tricky question. Also read wikipage on [fork syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29). We don't have time to teach you that here.

Comment: One hint. Look at the process IDs (PIDs). The parent maintains the original PID while the child receives a new PID. Also, the former is set up as the parent PID of the later.

Comment: `fork()` is called once, but ends up returning twice, in two different processes.  The O/S is responsible for ensuring this happens; it creates a copy of the process and ensures that the two returns occur correctly.

Comment: When fork makes a copy of the current process, it isn't an *exact* copy. One of the things that's different is the value to be returned by fork().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `fork()` is called, a process spawns a child process with shared or duplicated process segments. What that means is that in a program, before `fork()` is called, there is only one process, or one unit of execution. After `fork()` returns, there are two processes running concurrently. Since both processes have the same call stack at this point, it looks to each processes as if it had just called `fork()`. In the parent process, the return value of `fork()` is the PID of the child process. In the child process, the return value of `fork()` is 0.

You can see this with a really simple demonstration:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    pid_t parent = getpid();
    pid_t child = fork();

    if(child != 0){
        printf("I am the parent process. My PID is %d\n", parent);
        printf("Parent process terminating\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("I am the child process. My PID is %d\n", getpid());
        printf("    My parent's PID is %d\n", parent);
        printf("Child process terminating\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a sample run on my laptop:

```
$ gcc -o fork fork.c
$ ./fork
I am the parent process. My PID is 16048
Parent process terminating
I am the child process. My PID is 16049
    My parent's PID is 16048
Child process terminating
$
```

Note that when you run this, the PIDs will be different. Also, the output is subject to a race condition, so sometimes, the parent process will return to the shell before the child process finished printing, so it might look like this:

```
$ ./fork
I am the parent process. My PID is 16265
Parent process terminating
$ I am the child process. My PID is 16266
    My parent's PID is 16265
Child process terminating
```

What's important to understand is that `fork()` causes the single process of execution to split into two independent units. Since each process is still spawned from the same program (or source code), the behaviour is the same for both processes. The reason their output differs is only due to the fact that `fork()` returns different values for parent or children processes.

Comment: I think he is asking how fork knows what to return. Not how you can tell based on the return value of fork.

Comment: To me, his question indicated general confusion regarding the use of forking, which is understandable considering its deviation from the typical single-threaded execution model. I figured that a demonstration would be clearer than sending him to technical references.

Comment: Yes,exactly how does fork() know what to return in child and parent processes ???

Comment: The first (parent) process calls the `fork()` system call, and the operating system figures out how to create a second (child) process that has an identical structure. This is OS dependent, but we can assume that any OS has a way of keeping track of which processes are running. Since system calls are capable of returning values just like a function, the system call returns the child PID to the parent processes, and 0 to the child process. It knows which value to return to which process, via the internal process bookkeeping.

Comment: @millinon i think, the question still remains. Please allow me to rephrase to perhaps get more clarity around the what the question is here: How does the system call know that now it is being executed as part of the child process and hence should return 0? Alternatively put, how does the system call know that it is being executed in the context of the parent process and hence it should return the child process' PID this time and not 0?

Comment: I am not really sure if this question gets opened back again for answers as it has been 8 years since it was closed. But I did come across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34871795/980153) and it seems to answer the exact question asked.

Comment: I genuinely love it when I stumble upon a SO question / answer that I made back in my college days. I'm glad that you find this topic interesting! I would say that the SO answer you linked is more of a deep dive into one particular implementation which definitely does have merit. However, in the context of the original question I think a generalized answer might be more useful.

Comment: In the context of the original question, I see three main components of a general answer:
1) It depends massively on the architecture being considered
2) Managing OS structures like threads and processes is one of the core responsibilities of the OS kernel
3) System calls like `fork()` usually involve context switching into the kernel, which grants access to the 'bookkeeping' information internal to the kernel