# Where is the source for the fork() call in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, fork

I've been spending quite some time trying to find the source code for the `fork()` function. I know that most of work done by `fork()` is done by `do_fork()` and that can be found in `kernel/fork.c`. However what I want to see is the source code for the `fork()` function.

Any ideas where it could be found? I've been going through GCC and Linux source code but still haven't managed to find it.

Edit: I'm trying to find the exact implementation my system is using. As mentioned in the comment and in this [Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87551/which-file-in-kernel-specifies-fork-vfork-to-use-sys-clone-system-call) Its apparently in some wrapper in glibc. Any idea where in glibc I can find the wrapper. I've searched throughly but couldn't find its definition.

Comment: The "wrapper" used by the GNU libc around the kernel do_fork is in the source to GNU libc.

Comment: @Programmer123 download your current linux kernel&glibc's source with your linux distribution's package command and then search

Comment: @arsane I've actually done that and have been searching around for the past few hours but nothing.

Comment: Why do you ask? `fork` is a system call, so from the user-land application point of view, it is an elementary atomic operation...

Comment: What Linux version are you looking at?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Taking as reference the x86 platform and the 2.6.23 Linux kernel:

- Create the `test-fork.c` file:

  ```
  #include <unistd.h>

  int main (void)
  {
      fork();
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Compile it with static linking: `gcc -O0 -static -Wall test-fork.c -o test-fork`
- Disassemble it: `objdump -D -S test-fork > test-fork.dis`
- Open the `test-fork.dis` file and search for `fork`:

  ```
          fork();
   80481f4:       e8 63 55 00 00          call   804d75c <__libc_fork>
          return 0;
   80481f9:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  }
   80481fe:       c9                      leave  
   80481ff:       c3                      ret
  ```
- Then search `__libc_fork`:

  ```
   0804d75c <__libc_fork>:
   804d75c:       55                      push   %ebp
   804d75d:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
   804d762:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   804d764:       53                      push   %ebx
   804d765:       83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
   804d768:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
   804d76a:       74 12                   je     804d77e <__libc_fork+0x22>
   804d76c:       c7 04 24 80 e0 0a 08    movl   $0x80ae080,(%esp)
   804d773:       e8 88 28 fb f7          call   0 <_init-0x80480d4>
   804d778:       83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp
   804d77b:       5b                      pop    %ebx
   804d77c:       5d                      pop    %ebp
   804d77d:       c3                      ret    
   804d77e:       b8 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%eax
   804d783:       cd 80                   int    $0x80
   804d785:       3d 00 f0 ff ff          cmp    $0xfffff000,%eax
   804d78a:       89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
   804d78c:       77 08                   ja     804d796 <__libc_fork+0x3a>
   804d78e:       89 d8                   mov    %ebx,%eax
   804d790:       83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp
   804d793:       5b                      pop    %ebx
   804d794:       5d                      pop    %ebp
   804d795:       c3                      ret
  ```

  Notice that on this particular hardware/kernel `fork` is associated with **syscall number 2**
- Download a copy of the Linux kernel: `wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.23.tar.bz2`
- Open the `linux-2.6.23/arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S` file
- Notice that the syscall number 2 is associated to

  ```
  sys_fork:
       .long sys\_fork   /* 2 */
  ```
- Open the `linux-2.6.23/arch/x86/kernel/process.c` file
- Search for `sys_fork`:

  ```
    asmlinkage int sys_fork(struct pt_regs regs)
    {
            return do_fork(SIGCHLD, regs.esp, &regs, 0, NULL, NULL);
    }
  ```

  Notice that `do_fork()` is called only with the `SIGCHLD` parameter
- Open the `linux-2.6.23/kernel/fork.c` file. Here is where `do_fork()` is defined!
- `do_fork()` then calls `copy_process()`:

  ```
    /*
     *  Ok, this is the main fork-routine.
     *
     * It copies the process, and if successful kick-starts
     * it and waits for it to finish using the VM if required.
     */
    long do_fork(unsigned long clone_flags,
                  unsigned long stack_start,
                  struct pt_regs *regs,
                  unsigned long stack_size,
                  int __user *parent_tidptr,
                  int __user *child_tidptr)
    {
            struct task_struct *p;
            int trace = 0;
            struct pid *pid = alloc_pid();
            long nr;

            if (!pid)
                    return -EAGAIN;
            nr = pid->nr;
            if (unlikely(current->ptrace)) {
                    trace = fork_traceflag (clone_flags);
                    if (trace)
                            clone_flags |= CLONE_PTRACE;
            }

            p = copy_process(clone_flags, stack_start, regs, stack_size, \
                             parent_tidptr, child_tidptr, pid);


         /*
           * Do this prior waking up the new thread - the thread 
           * pointer might get invalid after that point, 
           * if the thread exits quickly.
           */
          if (!IS_ERR(p)) {
                  struct completion vfork;

                  if (clone_flags & CLONE_VFORK) {
                          p->vfork_done = &vfork;
                          init_completion(&vfork);
                  }

                  if ((p->ptrace & PT_PTRACED) || \
                      (clone_flags & CLONE_STOPPED)) {
                          /*
                           * We'll start up with an immediate SIGSTOP.
                           */
                          sigaddset(&p->pending.signal, SIGSTOP);
                          set_tsk_thread_flag(p, TIF_SIGPENDING);
                  }

                  if (!(clone_flags & CLONE_STOPPED))
                          wake_up_new_task(p, clone_flags);
                  else
                          p->state = TASK_STOPPED;

                  if (unlikely (trace)) {
                          current->ptrace_message = nr;
                          ptrace_notify ((trace << 8) | SIGTRAP);
                  }

                   if (clone_flags & CLONE_VFORK) {
                            freezer_do_not_count();
                            wait_for_completion(&vfork);
                            freezer_count();
                            if (unlikely (current->ptrace & \
                                          PT_TRACE_VFORK_DONE)) {
                                    current->ptrace_message = nr;
                                    ptrace_notify \
                                      ((PTRACE_EVENT_VFORK_DONE << 8) | \
                                        SIGTRAP);
                            }
                    }
            } else {
                    free_pid(pid);
                    nr = PTR_ERR(p);
            }
            return nr;
    }
  ```
- **The bulk of the work in forking is handled by `do_fork()`,
  defined in `kernel/fork.c`**. Operations performed by **`do_fork()`**:

  - It allocates a new PID for the child by calling `alloc_pid()`
  - It checks the `ptrace` field of the parent (i.e. `current->ptrace`)

    - If it is not zero, the parent process is being traced by another process
  - It calls **`copy_process()`**, which sets up the process descriptor and any other kernel data structure required for child's execution

    - Its parameters are the same as `do_fork()` plus the PID of the child
    - It checks if the flags passed in the `clone_flags` parameter are compatible
    - It performs additional security checks by invoking `security_task_create()` and `security_task_alloc()`
    - It calls **`dup_task_struct()`** which creates new kernel stack, `thread_info` and `task_struct` structures for the new process.

      - The new values are identical to those of current task
      - At this point child and parent process descriptors are identical
      - It executes the `alloc_task_struct()` macro to get a `task_struct` structure for the new process, and stores its address in the `tsk` local variable.
      - It executes the `alloc_thread_info` macro to get a free memory area to store the `thread_info` structure and the Kernel Mode stack of the new process, and saves its address in the `ti` local variable
      - It copies the contents of the current's process descriptor into the `task_struct` structure pointed to by `tsk`, then it sets `tsk->thread_info` to `ti`
      - It copies the contents of the current's `thread_info` descriptor into the structure pointed to by `ti`, then it sets `ti->task` to `tsk`
      - It sets the usage counter of the new process descriptor (i.e. `tsk->usage`) to 2 to specify that the process descriptor is in use and that the corresponding process is alive (its state is not `EXIT_ZOMBIE` or `EXIT_DEAD`)
      - It returns the process descriptor pointer of the new process (i.e. `tsk`)
    - `copy_process()` then checks if the maximum amount of processes for the current user has not been exceeded (i.e. greater than `max_threads)
  - It differentiates the child from the parent by clearing or initilizing various fields of the `task_struct`
  - It calls `copy_flags()` to update the `flags` field of the `task_struct`

    - The `PF_SUPERPRIV` (which denotes if a task used superuser privileges) and `PF_NOFREEZE` flags are cleared
    - The `PF_FORKNOEXEC` flag (which denotes if a task has not called `exec()) is set
    - It calls `init_sigpending() that clears the pending signals
    - Depending on the parameters passed to `do_fork(),`copy_process()` then duplicates or shares resources
    - Open files
    - Filesystem information
    - Signal handlers
    - Address space
    - It calls `sched_fork()` which splits the remaining timeslice between parent and child
    - Finally, it returns a pointer to the new child
  - Then, `do_fork()` adds a pending `SIGSTOP` signal in case the `CLONE_STOPPED` flag is set or the child process must be traced (i.e. the `PT_PTRACED` flag is set in `p->ptrace`)
  - If the `CLONE_STOPPED` flag is not set, it invokes the `wake_up_new_task()` function, which performs the following operations:

    - It adjusts the scheduling parameters of both the parent and the child
    - If the child will run on the same CPU as the parent and parent and child do not share the same set of page tables (i.e. `CLONE_VM` flag cleared), it then forces the child to run before the parent by inserting it into the parent's runqueue right before the parent. This simple step yields better performance if the child flushes its address space and executes a new program right after the forking. If we let the parent run first, the *Copy On Write* mechanism would give rise to a series of unnecessary page duplications.
    - Otherwise, if the child will not be run on the same CPU as the parent, or if parent and child share the same set of page tables (i.e.
      `CLONE_VM` flag set), it inserts the child in the last position of the parent's runqueue
  - Otherwise, if the `CLONE_STOPPED` flag is set, it puts the child in the `TASK_STOPPED` state
  - If the parent process is being traced, it stores the PID of the child in
    the `ptrace_message` field of `current` and invokes
    `ptrace_notify()`, which essentially stops the current process and sends a `SIGCHLD` signal to its parent. The ``grandparent'' of the child is the debugger that is tracing the parent; the `SIGCHLD` signal notifies the debugger that current has forked a child, whose PID can be retrieved by looking into the `current->ptrace_message` field.
  - If the `CLONE_VFORK` flag is specified, it inserts the parent process in a wait queue and suspends it until the child releases its memory address space (that is, until the child either terminates or executes a new program)
- It terminates by returning the PID of the child.

Comment: wonderful thank you. I actually printed out the assembly code didn't get much from there. Didn't come to my mind to create the object dump. Thanks again.

Comment: Note that this answer was for Linux 2.6.23; my answer was for Linux 4.4 - it looks like there is significant differences with how the ``fork()`` syscall is defined in the two versions. The code I quoted is not in Linux 2.6.23.

Comment: My goodness that's a long and thorough answer.  I wish I could up-vote you a few extra times.  :)

Answer (score 6):

From http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/fork.c#L1787 which is for Linux 4.4:

```
1787 #ifdef __ARCH_WANT_SYS_FORK
1788 SYSCALL_DEFINE0(fork)
1789 {
1790 #ifdef CONFIG_MMU
1791         return _do_fork(SIGCHLD, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
1792 #else
1793         /* can not support in nommu mode */
1794         return -EINVAL;
1795 #endif
1796 }
1797 #endif
```

I believe this is where it defines the fork syscall. Under Linux I believe that the glibc `fork()` function calls this syscall directly without doing anything else.

Comment: Nope. glibc calls `clone()` to implement `fork()`.

Comment: brilliant thank you. All these macros make it really hard for noobes like me to read the code :)

Comment: @FUZxxl I believe ``__libc_fork()`` does call the ``fork()`` syscall, not ``clone()``, see the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to glibc file
[fork.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fork.c)