# How can I fork exactly 6 processes

Tags: c, process, fork

To start, this is a homework problem so I am not looking for someone to spoon me the answer. I am just hoping to be pointed in the right direction.

I was given the task of creating exactly 6 processes using the c language and the command fork() and then have all 6 sleep for a minute or two. The tougher part with this is that we are not allowed to use any loops at all, and only 3 calls to fork() total. Almost all of the information regarding fork and n number of processes tells the user to use a for loop. I have also looked on here to find something similar, but again, for loops.

I have managed to create 8 successfully but that is too many. So I was wondering if it is possible to fork or kill specific processes.

For instance: given the first fork, you get the parent process and the child process. Fork again and you have the original parent with 2 children and the first child with one child. Would it then be possible to fork() only the original child that has a child? Everything I've found seems to say that whatever occurs after the fork call is executed by all forked processes so I am unsure how to effect what I need to do.

Comment: Six explicit calls to `fork` *in the parent only*?

Comment: Sorry I changed the question a little to explain more. I can only call fork() 3 times in the code total.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387349/how-does-the-fork-know-whether-it-is-in-child-process-and-in-parent-process

Comment: Do you know who to (in code) determine whether the process is the parent or the child (after the call to fork). If you do, the rest is bookkeeping. For instance, if you have a variable keeping track of the # of times a fork has occurred, and the child does the forking...

Comment: My hangup has been in how to specify parent or child during forking in addition to being unsure if it is possible to fork only a specific process (for instance if I wanted to fork only the original process after some time and instructions have passed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to use the return value of `fork` (< 0 is an error, == 0 is the child and > 0 is the parent process) to let the first child not calling `fork` to get 3 processes:

```
//we start with 1 process
if (fork() > 0) //now we have 2 processes
    fork(); //only the parent calls this fork because of the if, so we have 3 processes
fork(); //all 3 processes calls this fork, so we have 6 processes
```

another possibility:

```
fork(); //2
if (fork() > 0) //4
    fork(); //only the 2 parents from the second call will call this ==> 6
```